# Comma splice rule exception when listing things

Tags: punctuation

I need help with the following sentence that I've encountered on the Wikipedia page titled "Literal and figurative language."

> His cheeks were like roses, his nose like a cherry...

Another example (from engVid Youtube video):

> I have one idea, I have another idea, but they are very much
>   connected.

Can somebody please support or disprove such an exception to the comma splice rule (when you list ideas or something like that).

PS If you say that "his nose like a cherry" is not an independent clause, then if the first sentence were to be written as follows:

> His cheeks were like roses, his nose was like a cherry...

would the comma still be acceptable/correct?

Comment: Although note that the question title is misleading.

Comment: @Edwin That's the best I was able to come up with based on the data I had. You can edit it if you wish. And by the way, while the answer to the question "Is it grammatically correct to combine 2 phrases into 1 sentence?" is what I was looking for, the title of the question is misleading, not helpful and ambiguous. Both "You're welcome" and "have a nice day ahead" are independent clauses. You could also call them phrases in the sense "idiomatic or short, pithy expressions."

Comment: However, another meaning of *phrase* is "a small group of words standing together as a conceptual unit, typically forming a component of a clause." Ambiguous and unhelpful title. And misleading. Should have been edited a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect. Two independent clauses can have period.
**His cheeks were like roses. His nose was like a cherry.**

If we want to connect them by 'and',  we can use comma.
**His cheeks were like roses, and his nose was like a cherry.**

Comment: So 'I came, I saw, I conquered' is wrong? This has been answered here before, and more accurately. I'll wait before downvoting.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth. Some grammatical rules are flexible for lyrics and poetry. That is called  'Poetic license'.

Comment: In the answer given previously is 'Strunk & White notes that splices are sometimes acceptable when the clauses are short and alike in form, such as:

The gate swung apart, the bridge fell, the portcullis was drawn up.' This is prose (though emphatic in style). 'Two independent clauses must not be joined by a comma' is a useful rule-of-thumb, but no more than that. Author Lynne Truss observes: "So many highly respected writers observe the splice comma that a rather unfair rule emerges on this one: only do it if you're famous." She cites Samuel Beckett, E. M. Forster, and Somerset Maugham.